# ¿Como guardar una encuesta socioeconómica?

Tags: mysql

Tengo un proyecto donde se guarda la información de una encuesta socio económica ya la tengo de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La encuesta es de 28 preguntas.
Todo funciona bien, la el gran problema que tengo es que por la gran cantidad de personas encuestadas, las consultas tardan demasiado en generarse, consulta de 500 personas tarda un aproximado de 1 minuto.
Entonces mi pregunta es como optimizar el guardado de información para que las consultas sean más rápidas.
El servidor que uso, es el de google cloud bitnami. tiene un CPU y 1.7GB de RAM. en las estadísticas no consume ni el 10% de CPU. 
este es el resultado de la consulta explain 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la consulta sql

```
SELECT
    usuario.id_usuario,
    usuario.usuario,
    usuario.nombre,
    usuario.apellido_paterno,
    usuario.apellido_materno,
    usuario.genero,
    catalogo_usuario_rol.id AS id_rol,
    catalogo_usuario_rol.nombre AS nombre_rol,
    usuario_informacion.calle,
    usuario_informacion.num_ext,
    usuario_informacion.num_int,
    usuario_informacion.calle2,
    usuario_informacion.referencia,
    usuario_informacion.telefono_fijo,
    usuario_informacion.celular,
    usuario_informacion.cp,
    usuario_informacion.fecha_nacimiento,
    usuario_informacion.entidad_nacimiento,
    usuario_informacion.clave_elector,
    usuario_informacion.curp,
    usuario_informacion.ocr,
    usuario_informacion.zona,
    usuario_informacion.seccion,
    catalogo_colonias.nombre AS nombre_colonia,
    (
    SELECT
        id_subdirector
    FROM
        relacion_coordinador_zona
    WHERE
        id_coordinador_zona = usuario.id_usuario
) AS id_subdirector,
(
    SELECT
        id_coordinador_zona
    FROM
        relacion_liderer_activo
    WHERE
        id_lider_activo = usuario.id_usuario
) AS id_coordinador_zona,
(
    SELECT
        id_lider_activo
    FROM
        relacion_ciudadano_activo
    WHERE
        id_ciudadano_activo = usuario.id_usuario
) AS id_lider_activo,
(
    SELECT
        id_ciudadano_activo
    FROM
        relacion_beneficiario
    WHERE
        id_beneficiario = usuario.id_usuario
) AS id_ciudadano_activo,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Personas migrantes" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "Sexualidad" WHEN respuesta = 3 THEN "Salud" WHEN respuesta = 4 THEN "Madre / Padre soltero(A)" WHEN respuesta = 5 THEN "Comunidades indigenas" WHEN respuesta = 6 THEN "Adulto Mayor" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 1
) AS p1,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Soltero" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "Casado" WHEN respuesta = 3 THEN "Unión libre" WHEN respuesta = 4 THEN "Viudo" WHEN respuesta = 5 THEN "Separado" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 2
) AS p2,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Analfabeta" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "Primaria" WHEN respuesta = 3 THEN "Secundaria" WHEN respuesta = 4 THEN "Preparatoria" WHEN respuesta = 5 THEN "Carrera técnica" WHEN respuesta = 6 THEN "Licenciatura" WHEN respuesta = 7 THEN "Maestría" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 3
) AS p3,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Empleado sector privado" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "Empleado gobierno municipal" WHEN respuesta = 3 THEN "Gobierno estatal" WHEN respuesta = 4 THEN "Gobierno federal" WHEN respuesta = 5 THEN "Obrero" WHEN respuesta = 6 THEN "Secretaria" WHEN respuesta = 7 THEN "Negocio propio" WHEN respuesta = 8 THEN "Comerciante / Ventas" WHEN respuesta = 9 THEN "Desempleado" WHEN respuesta = 10 THEN "Agrcolas/Pecuarias" WHEN respuesta = 11 THEN "Artesano" WHEN respuesta = 12 THEN "Hogar" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 4
) AS p4,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Si" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "No" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 5
) AS p5,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 6
) AS p6,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Mayor a 1500" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "Menor a 1500" ELSE ""
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 7
) AS p7,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 8
) AS p8,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Si" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "No" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 9
) AS p9,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 10
) AS p10,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "IMMS" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "ISSEMYM" WHEN respuesta = 3 THEN "ISSSTE" WHEN respuesta = 4 THEN "Seguro popular" WHEN respuesta = 5 THEN "Servicio particular" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 11
) AS p11,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 12
) AS p12,
(
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            (
                CASE WHEN respuesta = 1 THEN "Afore" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "Aguinaldo" WHEN respuesta = 3 THEN "Infonavit" WHEN respuesta = 4 THEN "Prima vacacional" WHEN respuesta = 5 THEN "Pensión" WHEN respuesta = 6 THEN "Seguro de vida" WHEN respuesta = 7 THEN "Vacaciones" ELSE "Error de captura"
            END
        )
)
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 13
) AS p13,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 14
) AS p14,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 15
) AS p15,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Si" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "No" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 16
) AS p16,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Agricola" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "Asentamiento irregular" WHEN respuesta = 3 THEN "Residencia" WHEN respuesta = 4 THEN "Rural" WHEN respuesta = 5 THEN "Semi rural" WHEN respuesta = 6 THEN "Urbana" WHEN respuesta = 7 THEN "Semi urbana" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 17
) AS p17,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Compartida" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "Familiar" WHEN respuesta = 3 THEN "Prestada" WHEN respuesta = 4 THEN "Propia" WHEN respuesta = 5 THEN "Rentada" WHEN respuesta = 6 THEN "Otro" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 18
) AS p18,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 19
) AS p19,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 20
) AS p20,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Adobe" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "Cemento" WHEN respuesta = 3 THEN "Lamina" WHEN respuesta = 4 THEN "Madera" WHEN respuesta = 5 THEN "Loseta" WHEN respuesta = 6 THEN "Piedra" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 21
) AS p21,
(
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            (
                CASE WHEN respuesta = 1 THEN "Agua potable" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "Drenaje" WHEN respuesta = 3 THEN "Gas" WHEN respuesta = 4 THEN "Internet" WHEN respuesta = 5 THEN "Cable TV" WHEN respuesta = 6 THEN "Teléfono fijo" WHEN respuesta = 7 THEN "Seguridad (Alarmas, cámaras)" WHEN respuesta = 8 THEN "Luz electrica" WHEN respuesta = 9 THEN "Alumbrado público" WHEN respuesta = 10 THEN "Transporte publico" WHEN respuesta = 11 THEN "Recolección de basura" WHEN respuesta = 12 THEN "Otro" ELSE "Error de captura"
            END
        )
)
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 22
) AS p22,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 23
) AS p23,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Si" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "No" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 24
) AS p24,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 25
) AS p25,
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        respuesta = 1 THEN "Si" WHEN respuesta = 2 THEN "No" ELSE "Error de captura"
END AS respuesta2
FROM
    usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
WHERE
    id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 26
) AS p26,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 27
) AS p27,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 28
) AS p28,
(
    SELECT
        respuesta
    FROM
        usuario_encuesta_socioeconomica
    WHERE
        id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario AND pregunta = 29
) AS p29
FROM
    usuario
JOIN usuario_informacion ON usuario.id_usuario = usuario_informacion.id_usuario
JOIN catalogo_colonias ON usuario_informacion.colonia = catalogo_colonias.id
JOIN catalogo_usuario_rol ON usuario.rol = catalogo_usuario_rol.id
ORDER BY usuario.rol DESC;
```

Comment: Necesitamos: tu consulta, que hagas uso de `EXPLAIN`, que nos indiques si haces uso de índices, etc; empieza por favor por leer [ask]

Comment: Ok, bueno, creo que si formule la pregunta o problema de esta manera es porque yo no sé cómo resolverla. Tampoco conozco de técnicas o métodos en MySQL que me puedan servir. Pero gracias de todos modos amigo

Comment: Pues precisamente por eso te digo como mejores tu pregunta por que de otro modo sin mas datos nosotros tampoco vamos a saber como ayudarte, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: También es importante que veamos los índices que tienes y por lo menos un ejemplo de una de tantas subconsultas. ¿Estas haciendo una subconsulta por pregunta?

Comment: si, para saber la respuesta de la pregunta de la encuesta